# Why widgets.js is being loaded in my cq5 publish instance?

Tags: aem

We need widgets javascript in author mode because we edit in author mode .But why my publish instance is loading widgets.js? Can anyone help me out

Answer (score 1):

There can be two possible reasons.

1. Your project specific clientlibs would have defined dependency over foundation clientlibs, due to which they are also getting included in publish along with your project specific ones.

If this is the case, remove the dependency and include the foundation clientlibs separately only when the `wcmmode` is not `disabled`.

2. You would have included foundation clientlibs for all modes instead of checking whether it is in edit / publish mode.

In this case, again modify the code to check the wcmmode and then include the foundation clientlibs.

Mostly you would find something like this

```
<% if (WCMMode.fromRequest(request) != WCMMode.DISABLED) { %>
    <cq:includeClientLib categories="cq.widgets" />
<% } %>
```